# match text vectors from two data frames and return sum of third vector

Tags: r, match

I have two data frames.

First one called : sentence

```
structure(list(Text = c("This is a pen", "this is a sword", "pen is mightier than a sword"
)), .Names = "Text", row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

which looks like:

```
                          Text
1                This is a pen
2              this is a sword
3 pen is mightier than a sword
```

Second one called : words

```
structure(list(wordvec = c("pen", "sword"), value = c(1, 2)), .Names = c("wordvec", 
"value"), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame")
```

which looks like:

```
  wordvec value
1     pen     1
2   sword     2
```

I have to search for words present in wordvec in sentence, and if they are present i have to return the sum of words.

Desired output is as follows:

```
                          Text   Value
1                This is a pen      1
2              this is a sword      2
3 pen is mightier than a sword      3
```

I first tried extracting the words present in sentence$Text matching with words$wordvec and made a vector.  This I successfully did.

```
library(stringi)

sentence$words <- sapply(stri_extract_all(sentence[[1]],regex='(#?)\\w+'),function(x) paste(x[x %in% words[[1]]],collapse=','))
```

As a next step i tried getting the sum of words present and create a vector sentence$value.  I tried the following code

```
sentence$value <- sum(words$value)[match(sentence$words, words$wordvec)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We `paste` the 'wordvec' as a single string, then extract the words from the 'Text' column that matches the pattern in a `list`, `match` with the 'wordvec' vector to get the position, based on that we get the corresponding 'value' from the 'words' and then we do the `sum`.

```
library(stringr)
sapply(str_extract_all(sentence$Text, 
       paste0('\\b(',paste(words$wordvec, collapse='|'), ')\\b')),
      function(x) sum(words$value[match(x, words$wordvec)]))
#[1] 1 2 3
```

---

Another option is using `strsplit` after converting the 'sentence' data.frame to data.table (`setDT(sentence,..)`), `match` the vector of split words with 'wordvec', get the corresponding 'value' and do the `sum`.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(sentence, keep.rownames=TRUE)[,
   sum(words$value[match(strsplit(Text, '\\s')[[1]], 
          words$wordvec, nomatch=0)]), by = rn]$V1
#[1] 1 2 3
```

Comment: @DavidArenburg pasting the word boundary or a space should fix it. (updated)

Comment: Thank you for all the comments.  I didn't read the full description initially as the `grep` gave the same result as the expected.

Comment: @DavidArenburg  Did you meant `setDT(sentence)[,newCol:= strsplit(Text, '\\s')][, sapply(newCol, function(x) sum(words$value[match(x, words$wordvec, nomatch=0)]))]` this?

Answer (score 1):

Here is another simple solution using the for loop. However performance might be an issue. Your dataframe:

```
sentence<-structure(list(Text = c("This is a pen", "this is a sword", "pen is mightier than a sword"
)), .Names = "Text", row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")

words<-structure(list(wordvec = c("pen", "sword"), value = c(1, 2)), .Names = c("wordvec", 
"value"), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame")
```

Create an empty dataframe with nrow as the number of counts of each word from wordvec.

```
a<-data.frame(matrix(0, ncol=1, nrow=nrow(sentence)))
```

Now using the for loop, go through every word in `words` and find it in sentence by using `str_count` from `stringr`. Using `cbind` you can store the number of times the word has been repeated in a dataframe for future reference. In this case `a`

```
for (i in 1:nrow(words))
a<-cbind(a,data.frame(count=str_count(sentence$Text,words$wordvec[i]))*words$value[i])
```

Now just add the sum of the rows by using `rowSums`

```
    data.frame(Text=sentence$Text,Value=rowSums(a))
```

and you will get:

```
                          Text Value
1                This is a pen     1
2              this is a sword     2
3 pen is mightier than a sword     3
>
```

Try it :)

Comment: Many thanks MaxPD, I tried your solution & it works flawlessly.  Thanks a ton for you help.